# How to authenticate a Google Cloud Function against a backend server

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, bearer-token

I'm using [Firebase Authentication Blocking Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/extend-with-blocking-functions)  (in particular `beforeCreate`) to register users in my own database before considering the Firebase signup as "done".

This Cloud Function needs to make a REST API call in order to create a resource. However, only this function should be authorised to call this endpoint.

I was planning to add a `'authorization': 'Bearer secretPassword'` header to my request and check that the password in the backend. Is this a bad practice? Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: 1) Using a text-passed password is considered bad practice. 2) Make sure that you are sending data via HTTPS. 3) Do not use the HTTP `Authorization`  or `X-Serverless-Authorization` headers [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token). Use an `X-` custom header for private usage. 4) Google has built-in support for creating and verifying OIDC ID Tokens. This will ensure that secrets are not leaked accidentally. This method is considered a best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When you mentioned that I should not use HTTP `Authorization` or `X-Serverless-Authorization` headers, do you mean that I should not use them because they are reserved for ID token authentication? Then, do you recommend generating/validating ID tokens as described in [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token)?

Comment: Your link, which is also the one I provided, shows how to use Google Cloud Authorization. The link also provides source code to generate and verify OIDC Identity Tokens (which is what I recommend). Do not use the reserved headers when sending requests to other Google Cloud services that support Authorization because IAP will then validate the tokens with IAM unless that is what you want to happen. If you wish to use something for private authorization use a private unreserved header starting with `X-`.